# implementing ASP strategy in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I've built several database driven web sites with ASP and I'm trying to migrate the basic functionality to an ASP.NET architecture.

I want to have each link in my navigation tree correspond to a different function that will step a user through various requests and provide sequential database driven responses and possible follow-up questions. I typically do this in ASP by using the query string to execute different parts of the code in an SSI file.  Each link in my navigation tree basically calls a different SSI file.

In ASP.NET I think I have a pretty good handle on web form basics, data binding, site navigation tools and master pages, but I'm having trouble with the overall design picture.

Do I want to have each link redirecting the user to different pages?  My understanding is that ASP.NET is much better at maintaining state information and so I shouldn't have to rely on the query string to keep passing values to an SSI file to do sequential parts of each task.

Should I be using BLL and DAL to do this and/or stored procedures and managed code?  Or could I do this sort of thing more simply with ASP.NET web pages, as  opposed to web forms?

Feedback that would include a reference article and/or web example would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Let me check my understanding from a very simple high-level overview...  In essence, you've got a Wizard-like interface to implement in ASP.NET?  (Stepping through various requests and varying follow-up questions based on previous questions is where I got that from)  Is that correct?

Comment: See comment below.  I'm new to stackoverflow and having trouble responding...

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to abandon your whole way of thinking and take up ASP.NET Web Forms.

I've been making sites with ASP.NET Web Forms since it came out in 2001.  But I think ASP.NET MVC would be an easier transition for you.  I mean, some things are more difficult in MVC than in Web Forms.  But on the whole, MVC will promote more web friendly practices and it's what I prefer now.

For example, the whole idea of postbacks and viewstate in Web Forms certainly makes a lot of things easier.  But they also have a problem of hurting SEO and breaking the back button.  MVC doesn't rely on any of this and it's easier to refine the user experience with the way form posts, redirects, and URLs are handled.

I wrote an article awhile back comparing MVC vs Web Forms...
http://swortham.blogspot.com/2009/10/when-to-use-aspnet-web-forms-and-when.html

Comment: +1.  Personally, I am not a fan of MVC, but that's my own problem.  I'm one of those bozos that actually likes the WebForms model.  ;-)  But I think your suggestion is good because MVC does look to be a lot more like classic ASP, and I'd think it would be an easier transition as well.

Comment: @DavidStratton - The past couple weeks I've been building a questionnaire made up of 300+ questions in MVC.  In the past I would've built form-heavy things like this in Web Forms.  But this was a part of an existing system in MVC.  Anyway, some things were more difficult.  But it wasn't too bad once I got going.  And yeah, I do think someone coming from classic ASP would have an easier time adapting to MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm seeing, it looks like you've got wizard-style navigation across multiple ASP pages, and you want to have wizard-style navigation in an ASP.NET (WebForms not MVC) site.

*If I'm misunderstanding this, I'll gladly delete this answer.*

I'd recommend the [Wizard control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx), ([Video demos available all over the place](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=asp.net%20Wizard%20control&FORM=HDRSC3)) which will provide such an interface in one page, reducing a lot of the complexity.  there's no need to keep track of variables across pages - it's all in one page, and therefore always accessible.

Wizard pages do tend to have a LOT of code and markup, but the trade-off is that all of the wizard functionality is in one pace, not scattered across files, and it's inherently obvious what's happening at each step.  With the multiple-file approach, a maintenance developer needs to trace which page posts to which page and spend more time understanding the design.

Comment: My first impression of the Wizard Control was that it might not be flexible enough for what I want, but as I play with it more, I see that it might do the job. So the jury is still out and I'm exploring both options.

Comment: Here's an example of an [Edit Call History Function] (https://bscintra.buffalostate.edu/chsr/callTracker/Sample.ppsx) that I used in an old ASP application. Is either the Wizard Control or MVC flexible enough to implement this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The article on MVC vs Web Forms was quite interesting, although after looking at a few training videos I got the impression that the coding is quite a bit different from ASP.  (Most of the examples I also see involve C#, although I have seen a few with VB, which is preferred since I'm already learning a lot of new things in a short time.) Also, I wonder if MVC will let me use the validation tools, which will be quite necessary in a different aspect of this project that involves several different and quite long forms. Given that I've invested a fair amount of time in learning about ASP.NET, I'm wondering if I should just go the extra mile (or two) and learn how to create business objects (BLL) and a data layer (DAL).

Comment: MVC 3 validation is summed up pretty well here... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249452/ASP-NET-MVC3-Validation-Basic